# Como passar um json contendo array de dados para o Php?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Como seria possível enviar o seguinte Json para o Php sem que se perca a parte de "**tabLinhas**", onde tem-se um array!? O Json original é composto por uma única linha, coloquei desta forma aqui somente para melhorar a visualização:

```
{"csTipoPagamento":"20",
"csClassificacao":"14",
"csContrato":"41",
"csFornecedor":"Nome_do_Fornecedor",
"csNotaFiscal":"2316549-9",
"csValorNotaFiscal":"2413.08",
"csCnpj":"Uma_numeração_de_CNPJ",
"csEmissao":"28/06/2015",
"csVencimento":"28/07/2015",
"csMunicipio":"275",
"csDtpInicial":"01/06/2015",
"csDtpFinal":"30/06/2015",
"csRefPgto":"9",
"csIngressSpd":"29/06/2015",
"csData":"02/07/2015",
"csLiId":"O_Id",
"csMedicao":"A_Medição",
"csPedido":"Numeração_do_pedido",
"csDtpRecebNota":"30/06/2015",
"csDescServico":"Uma_Descrição",
"csObservacoes":"Uma_Observação",
"tabLinhas":[
["33","12","102","1","12","2413.08","569659","201.09"],
["33","12","102","1","12","2413.08","569659","201.09"]
]}
```

Já tentei da seguinte forma:

No Javascript:

```
var str_json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
request= new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "recebeJson.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.send(str_json);
alert(str_json); //Exibe o json perfeitamente na janela de alerta
```

No Php, recebendo o Json via POST:

```
var_dump($_POST);
echo '<br><br>Erro(s): '.json_last_error();
```

Saída do var_dump do POST Php:

```
array(16) {
  ["csTipoPagamento"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["csClassificacao"]=> string(2) "15"
  ["csContrato"]=> string(1) "6"
  ["csNotaFiscal"]=> string(9) "3126549-2"
  ["csEmissao"]=> string(10) "29/06/2015"
  ["csVencimento"]=> string(10) "29/07/2015"
  ["csMunicipio"]=> string(3) "309"
  ["csCecoAprov"]=> string(6) "CJ9700"
  ["csDtpInicial"]=> string(10) "01/06/2015"
  ["csDtpFinal"]=> string(10) "30/06/2015"
  ["csRefPgto"]=> string(1) "9"
  ["csIngressSpd"]=> string(10) "28/06/2015"
  ["csPedido"]=> string(15) "Pedido qualquer"
  ["csDtpRecebNota"]=> string(10) "29/06/2015"
  ["csDescServico"]=> string(13) "Uma Descrição"
  ["csObservacoes"]=> string(14) "Uma Observação"
}
```

Saída do json_last_error():

```
Erro(s): 0
```

Após o POST, além de já estar chegando como array, estou perdendo algumas deste.

Comment: E o que acontece dessa forma?

Comment: Da forma como fiz, toda a parte final, a de **tabLinhas**, é perdida entre o envio no Js e o recebimento no Php.

Comment: Porquen dizes que é perdida? Como estás a usar esse JSON no PHP? coloca ocódigo pf

Answer (score 1):

Experimente utilizando a biblioteca jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input["type=submit"]').on('click',function(){
        var data = $('#data_json').val();

          $.post('recebeJson.php',data:data,function(ret) {
             var retorno = $.parseJSON(ret);
             if (retorno.success) {
                alert('Dados enviados com sucesso!');
             }

          });
     return false;
     });
});
</script>
<form>
<input type='hidden' value='{"csTipoPagamento":"20","csClassificacao":"14","csContrato":"41","csFornecedor":"Nome_do_Fornecedor","csNotaFiscal":"2316549-9","csValorNotaFiscal":"2413.08","csCnpj":"Uma_numeração_de_CNPJ","csEmissao":"28/06/2015","csVencimento":"28/07/2015","csMunicipio":"275","csDtpInicial":"01/06/2015","csDtpFinal":"30/06/2015","csRefPgto":"9","csIngressSpd":"29/06/2015","csData":"02/07/2015","csLiId":"O_Id","csMedicao":"A_Medição","csPedido":"Numeração_do_pedido","csDtpRecebNota":"30/06/2015","csDescServico":"Uma_Descrição","csObservacoes":"Uma_Observação","tabLinhas":[["33","12","102","1","12","2413.08","569659","201.09"],["33","12","102","1","12","2413.08","569659","201.09"]]}' id='data_json'>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

E no PHP:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];

$objData = json_decode($data);

$dadosTabLinhas = $objData->tabLinhas;

echo 'exibe array dados:<br /> <pre>';
print_r($dadosTabLinhas);
?>
```

Comment: Usar o `$_POST[data]` parece uma ótima alternativa +1

Answer (score 0):

Não está perdendo o valor não, experimenta fazer assim:

```
/* no caso aqui eu forcei, mas é a mesma coisa que você envia com o JSON.stringify */
$json = json_decode('{"csTipoPagamento":"20","csClassificacao":"14","csContrato":"41","csFornecedor":"Nome_do_Fornecedor","csNotaFiscal":"2316549-9","csValorNotaFiscal":"2413.08","csCnpj":"Uma_numeração_de_CNPJ","csEmissao":"28/06/2015","csVencimento":"28/07/2015","csMunicipio":"275","csDtpInicial":"01/06/2015","csDtpFinal":"30/06/2015","csRefPgto":"9","csIngressSpd":"29/06/2015","csData":"02/07/2015","csLiId":"O_Id","csMedicao":"A_Medição","csPedido":"Numeração_do_pedido","csDtpRecebNota":"30/06/2015","csDescServico":"Uma_Descrição","csObservacoes":"Uma_Observação","tabLinhas":[["33","12","102","1","12","2413.08","569659","201.09"],["33","12","102","1","12","2413.08","569659","201.09"]]}');

foreach ($json->tabLinhas as $key=>$value) { //entra no tabLinhas
    echo "\n" . $key . ": " . $value;
    foreach ($value as $k=>$v) { //cada array do tabLinhas
         echo $k . ": " . $v . ", ";
    }
}
```

**Saída:**

> 0: Array0: 33, 1: 12, 2: 102, 3: 1, 4: 12, 5: 2413.08, 6: 569659, 7: 201.09,
>
> 1: Array0: 33, 1: 12, 2: 102, 3: 1, 4: 12, 5: 2413.08, 6: 569659, 7: 201.09,

### [IdeOne Exemplo](https://ideone.com/JEZEdh)

Comment: Maicon, com a variável Php já contendo esse mesmo Json funciona ok mesmo. Mas o problema realmente parece ser na passagem via POST para o Php. Neste momento é que perco as informações...

Answer (score 0):

Testei aqui com o seu código e consegui fazer funcionar com a seguinte mudança.

No arquivo `recebeJson.php`, coloquei o seguinte conteúdo:

```
$json =  json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true) ?: [];
var_dump($json);
```

Espero que isso lhe ajude.